# Running Webjet Admin on Server '08

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm having issues running Webjet Admin on server '08. I have changed the SQL Server Browser to Automatic, then to Manual, and neither have worked. It will install, but when I open it up, it will display the "Waiting for service start" prompt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You switched the startup type, but did you actually *start* the service?  Switching the startup type doesn't start the service automatically, unless you switch to automatic and reboot.  Right-click on the service and click Start.